# How to create an LinkedList<Object[]>[]?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, linked-list

What would be the syntax to create a `LinkedList<Object[]>[]` type variable?

I have tried:

```
public LinkedList<Object[]>[] myList = new LinkedList<Object[]>()[];
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853411/array-type-in-generics

Comment: I smell a generic design problem. Have you ever heard of javabeans?

Comment: It's an Android app. :D @Atreys, thanks for the helpful link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't create generic arrays. You can however do this with `ArrayList` class or any class that implements the `List` interface.

```
List<LinkedList<Object[]>> myList = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Object[]>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `LinkedList<Object[]>[]` means an **array** of lists of arrays - is that the intention?
Assuming that it is, you create it with the syntax for creating arrays:

```
public LinkedList<Object[]>[] myArray = new LinkedList[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

This creates an array of the specified size (`ARRAY_SIZE`), each cell of which is `null`.

Note that:

- Since you can't create generic arrays in Java, as [Hunter McMillen noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961783/how-to-create-an-linkedlistobject/6961825#6961825), the right part omits the type of the `LinkedList` (i.e. "`<Object[]>`").
- I took the liberty of renaming the variable from `myList` to `myArray`, since it's an array and not a list.
- It's usually a good idea to use the interface (`List`) and not a specific implementation (`LinkedList`), *unless* you need to use methods specific to `LinkedList`.

So the line would look like this:

```
public List<Object[]>[] myArray = new List[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Comment: Creating an array or List without specifying the type of the right hand side is an unsafe operation.